# Why do conflicts occur even after merging patches into the destination branch?

Tags: git

My project has a `develop` and `production` branch. While the `develop` branch is ahead of `production` carrying new work, some patches have gone straight to `production`, having caused both branches to diverge.

My incentive now is to pull in the patches from `production`, eradicating the merge conflicts between the branches, and making the next release possible.

My steps:

1. Created a new branch from `production`
2. Merged the changes from `develop` into my working branch, resolved all merge conflicts
3. Merged my working branch into the `develop` branch

When I now try to merge develop into `production`, new merge conflicts occur. Why is this happening?

Comment: Because the commit sequence does matter.

Comment: A more common approach is to simply merge `prod` into `dev`, or to rebase `dev` on `prod`.

Answer (score 1):

Merge conflicts:

1. are normal;
2. do require human intervention, because Git is not *smart*.

> Why is this happening?

A merge conflict occurs when two different changes overlap or abut.  To understand this, we need to know how Git sees the world.

#### Commits, or how Git sees the world

Git is all about *commits*.  Each commit has two parts, both of which are completely read-only:

- A commit has a *snapshot of all files*.  The files inside this snapshot are stored in a special, compressed, Git-only format, with de-duplication applied.  The de-duplication—which works both across and *within* commits—makes sure that the repository stays relatively slim, even if there are a million commits, each with a million files: most of those commits mostly share most of those files with most other commits, and those files appear only *once* in the repository.
- A commit stores some *metadata*, or information about the commit.  This includes the name and email address of the person who made the commit.  It includes some date-and-time-stamps.  It includes a log message, that you see when you run `git log`, telling you *why* they made that commit.  And, crucially for Git itself, each commit records the raw hash IDs of a list of *previous* commits.

The way Git actually finds any given commit is that you must give Git the raw hash ID of that commit—a big ugly string like [<sup><sub>`dcc0cd074f0c639a0df20461a301af6d45bd582e`</sub></sup>](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dcc0cd074f0c639a0df20461a301af6d45bd582e)—or anything that Git can use to *find* the hash ID of that commit.  Branch and tag names are human-readable strings (readable because we humans *make* them) that allow Git to find a hash ID.  By including some *previous* commit hash ID, a commit itself *also* provides Git with a way to find the *previous* commit.

Hence, by stringing a bunch of commits together, one at a time, with each commit "pointing backwards" to the previous one, Git gives us a nice simple linear chain of commits:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where `H` stands for the real (random-looking) hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain.  Commit `H` contains both a snapshot and metadata; the snapshot of all files gets us the files, and the metadata gets us the name of the person who made commit `H` and so on.

That metadata include the raw hash ID of *earlier* commit `G` though.  So Git can use commit `H` to find commit `G`.  Commit `G` has a snapshot of all files, and Git can *compare* the snapshot *in* `G` to the snapshot in `H`.  Whatever files are the same, those files weren't changed.  For each file that's *different*, Git can compare the contents of the changed files, and tell us what changed *in* those files.

By looking up both commits `G` and `H`, Git can therefore show us what *changed* in commit `H`.  Of course, commit `G` also has metadata, including the hash ID of an earlier commit `F`.  So having shown us commit `H` as changes from commit `G`, Git can now look up commit `F` and extract its snapshot, and compare those files to `G`'s files and see what changed.  Git can therefore show us commit `G`—including author and date and log message—as a set of *changes* from earlier commit `F`.

Of course, commit `F` is a commit, with a snapshot and metadata ... well, you can see where this is going now, right?  *Every* commit has an *earlier* commit, except for the very first commit, which Git has to handle as a special case.  As long as we don't think about that first commit too hard, it's all pretty obvious now.  (If you want to think about that first commit, the way Git handles this special case is to pretend, for the duration of trying to show the first commit, that there's one earlier commit that *has no files* in it.  That way every file *in* the first commit is newly-created.  Then, having shown the first commit, Git stops moving backwards, since there really isn't a previous commit after all.)

#### Branch names help us—and Git—find commits; what it means to be "on a branch"

In my mini-diagram:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

commit `H` was the *newest* commit.  It has some hash ID.  We have to give Git this hash ID.  I mentioned that a branch name stores a hash ID, so let's draw that in:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- somebranch
```

That is, the *name* `somebranch` *points to* commit `H`.  Commit `H` points back to earlier commit `G`, which points back to `F`, and so on.  I've stopped drawing the arrows between commits *as* arrows, because we're about to introduce "branchiness" and I don't have a good font drawing arrows here:

```
          I--J   <-- branch-1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch-2
```

Here, there is no longer a single "last commit": there are now **two** "last" commits, `J` and `L`.  `J` is the last commit *on* `branch-1`, and `L` is the last commit *on* `branch-2`.

The commit before `J`, which is commit `I`, is on `branch-1` as well.  The commit before `I`—commit `H`—is on `branch-1`, and the commits before `H` are all on `branch-1`.  Meanwhile the commit before `L`, or commit `K`, is on `branch-2`.  But what about the commit before `K`, i.e., commit `H`?  Is it on `branch-2`?  Git says *yes!*  Commit `H` is on *both branches*.  So are the earlier commits, `G` and `F` and so on, backwards down the line.

This means that commits can be on *more than one branch at a time*.  That's very important.

#### Adding new commits, or how we got commit `L`

At some point, we might well have had this:

```
          I--J   <-- branch-1
         /
...--G--H   <-- branch-2
```

Note how commits `H` and `G` and so on are on both branches, but commit `H` is currently the *last* commit on `branch-2` (while commit `J` is the *last* commit on `branch-1`).

We now choose to `git switch branch-2` or `git checkout branch-2`.  These both do the same thing: they make `branch-2` our *current branch*, and `H` our *current commit*.  Git will extract all the files *from* commit `H` so that we can work on / with them.

We do our work and `git add` files and `git commit`, and Git makes a *new commit*, which we'll call `K`.  Git makes this commit by:

- saving, permanently and with de-duplication, all the files that are in Git's index / staging-area (we will not cover this concept properly here, but this is where the files *in* a commit come from);
- adding the commit metadata, including our name and email address, a log message we give with `-m` or by editing a file or whatever, and saving the *current* commit's hash ID—whatever big ugly random-looking string of letters and digits `H` stands in for—as the *parent* of the new commit; and
- **writing the new commit `K`'s hash ID, whatever that is, into the *current branch name*.**

It's this last step that causes the branch name, `branch-2`, to remember new commit `K`:

```
          I--J   <-- branch-1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K   <-- branch-2 (HEAD)
```

This is how branches grow, in Git.  Or rather, it's how they grow one commit at a time—sometimes they grow in leaps and bounds by adding many commits all at once; we'll see that in a moment.  The `(HEAD)` I added to the drawing here shows which branch we have *checked out*.

Since Git just *made* commit `K` from the files in Git's index / staging-area, commit `K` and the index/staging-area match.  If we `git add`-ed all of our changes, this also matches our working tree, and we're ready to make commit `L` by changing more files, running `git add`, and running `git commit`:

```
          I--J   <-- branch-1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch-2 (HEAD)
```

#### Merging

We're ready to see how merging works now.  Remember that each commit holds a full snapshot of every file, and that we can use `git diff` or `git show` to compare the snapshots in adjacent commits, like `I`-vs-`J` or `H`-vs-`I` or whatever, to see what changed in each commit.  But what if we use `git diff` to compare the snapshot in `H` to the snapshot in `J`, skipping right over the snapshot in `I`?  (Think about this for a while, if you haven't before.)

Remember too that merging is about *combining work*.  But how should we define "work" here?  We already have some good examples: if we look at commit `K` as a *change*, the work done is whatever is *different* between the snapshot in `K`'s parent `H` and the snapshot in `K` itself.  We *see* this difference with `git diff hash-of-H hash-of-K` or `git show hash-of-K`.  The work done in commit `L` is the difference between `K` and `L`.  The work done in both commits is the difference between the snapshots in `H` and `L`: we don't have to look *at* the snapshot in `K`, because the snapshot *in* `L` *contains* that work, to whatever extent we didn't choose to *undo* it in commit `L`.

In other words, the differences between any pair of snapshots amounts to "the work done from the starting commit to the ending commit".  This `git diff` switches our point of view from *snapshot* to *set of changes*, and that's the work that we (or whoever) did.

Note that Git's diff listings here are *line oriented*.  We can ask for `--word-diff` but the way Git does that is to do a line diff, then tweak it for display.  Git internally always represents these changes as *remove some line(s)* and *add some line(s)*.  Some difference engines have a third thing they call *change some lines*, but those are really just *remove the old lines and put in the new lines*, so Git doesn't bother with that.

Now, given our drawing, what happens if we make *two* diffs, both of which start from the *same shared commit `H`* that is on both branches?  We'll get one diff:

```
git diff <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>   # what someone changed on branch-1
```

and another diff:

```
git diff <hash-of-H> <hash-of-L>   # what someone changed on branch-2
```

These diffs represent the *work done*, and *both start from the same snapshot in commit `H`*.  So if we have Git *combine* the two sets of changes, and apply the *combined* changes to the snapshot in `H`, we'll get a new snapshot—let's call it commit `M` for Merge—that contains *both sets of work*.  We can draw this in:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M
         \    /
          K--L
```

Commit `M`, our new *merge commit*, will—so that Git can "know" where `M` came from—link back to *both* `J` *and* `L`.  So that's why `M` has two backwards arrows coming out of it, one pointing up-and-left to `J`, and one pointing down-and-left to `L`.

What about our *branch names?*  Well, Git always works by stuffing the new commit's hash ID into the *current branch name*.  So if we run:

```
git switch branch-1
git merge branch-2
```

the picture will look like this:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- branch-1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- branch-2
```

If we instead use `git switch branch-2` and then `git merge branch-1`, we'll make the same *merge commit*—well, almost; see below—but we'll have this instead:

```
          I--J   <-- branch-1
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- branch-2 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L
```

The "combining work" goes the same either way, but commit `M` winds up the new "last" commit on whichever branch we're "on" when we run `git merge`.  So we should `git checkout` the correct branch.

Because `M` has *two* parents, whatever branch we're "on" when we run `git merge` now has *all the commits on it*.  That is, if the name `branch-1` points to commit `M`, *all* commits are now on `branch-1`.  Commits `K-L` used to be only on `branch-2`; now they're on *both branches*.  Commits `I-J` used to be only on `branch-1` and are still only on `branch-1`, because `branch-2` points to `L`, not `M`.

> Side note: when there are two parents, as in the case of `M`, one parent is the *first parent* and the remaining parent, well, isn't.  This has no effect on the merge *result*, but later, you can ask Git to follow only the *first* parent.  When we do that, if you're on `branch-1` when you run the merge, the *first* parent will be commit `J`, and Git will list commits in the order `M`, `J`, `I`, `H`, `G`, and so on: commits `L` and `K` are simply *not listed*.  But if you're on `branch-2` when you run the merge, the *first* parent will be commit `L`, and Git will list `M`, `L`, `K`, `H`, `G`, and so on: commits `I-J` get omitted.  So `--first-parent`, when you use it, means *follow the branch I was on, not the branches I merged.*

#### Summary and definitions

Merging is about *combining work*.  Running `git merge` starts with your *current commit*, whatever that is: Git finds out by looking at `HEAD`.  The name `HEAD` is normally *attached to* some branch name like `branch-1`:

```
          I--J   <-- branch-1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch-2
```

You make this happen using `git checkout` or `git switch`: this attaches `HEAD` to the branch name you use, while checking out the *commit* to which that branch name points.

The `git merge` command needs to know which *commit* to merge.  Usually, we pick a commit by picking a branch name: `branch-2` means *commit `L`*.  The actual merging works by *commits:* as usual in Git, the branch names, if any, just serve to find the commits.  (It's possible to do work in Git with *no branch names at all*.  It is just that you have to be crazy to do that.  Typing in raw hash IDs all day is insane: if you aren't already insane, you will be afterward. )

Having found the commit—such as commit `L`—the merge command now reads through the *commit graph*, which is the thing we've been drawing here.  It steps back, one commit at a time, from each of the *last* commits—the `HEAD` one, and the other one we named on the command line when we ran `git merge—until it finds the *best shared commit*.  "Best" here means, very roughly, "closest to the two commits we're merging".

This *best shared commit* has a name: Git calls it the *merge base*.  There are some (rare) occasions when there is more than one "best" commit, but we'll ignore those entirely here, and assume that, as in this case, there is a single merge base: commit `H`.

Having found the *merge base*, `git merge` then runs *two* `git diff` commands.  One compares the snapshot in the merge base to the snapshot in `HEAD`: this is *what we changed*.  The second diff compares the snapshot in the merge base to the snapshot in the other commit we named: this is *what they changed*.  The merge action now *combines the changes*.

#### Merge conflicts

A *merge conflict* occurs when:

- the diff from the merge base commit—`H` in our example—to our commit says *make a change at line 123 of file F,* and
- the diff from the merge base to their commit says *make a different change at line 123 of file F*.

Git doesn't know whether to use our change, or their change.  You'll see *conflict markers* in the file stored in the working tree, showing both sets of changes.

A conflict *also* occurs when:

- the diff for our changes says "delete line 3", and
- the diff for their changes says "add a line right after line 3"

for instance.  This is because our two changes *touch*.  The people who write merge algorithms have found that this kind of change, if taken quietly without a conflict, often produces bad results.  So it's called a conflict, even though it would be possible to just take both changes.

A conflict *also* occurs when:

- the diff for our change says "add this line after line 42", and
- the diff for their change says "add this different line after line 42"

for instance.  This is again because our two changes *touch*.  There is a merge algorithm, called *union merge*, that simply takes both changes, in some apparently-random order, but again this tends not work work very well in practice, so Git's default merge algorithm calls this a conflict.

A conflict *does not* occur when:

- the diff for our change says *remove or replace or add some lines here*, and
- the diff for their change says to do *exactly the same thing*.

In this case, Git assumes that doing this single change once is correct.  That's *not actually always true*, but this particular case arises quite often from the act of copying a single change, from a single commit, into another branch.  That is, suppose we have:

```
       E--F--G   <-- branch-1 (HEAD)
      /
...--D
      \
       H--I--J   <-- branch-2
```

and we discover that commit `I` fixes a nasty bug.  We're not ready to *merge* `branch-2` yet, but we can tell Git to *copy* commit `I` into our branch, as new commit `I'`, that makes the *same change* as commit `I`, using `git cherry-pick`:

```
       E--F--G--I'  <-- branch-1 (HEAD)
      /
...--D
      \
       H--I--J   <-- branch-2
```

We go on to make a few more commits (and perhaps they do too):

```
       E--F--G--I'--K   <-- branch-1 (HEAD)
      /
...--D
      \
       H--I--J------L   <-- branch-2
```

and we're now ready to `git merge branch-2`.  The change we got from their commit `I`, as our commit `I'`, would likely cause a conflict if Git didn't just accept it, even though it overlaps exactly.

But if our commit `K` touched one of the lines they changed in `I`, or if we changed an abutting line in `E`, `F`, `G`, or `K`, we'll get a *merge conflict*.  In fact, if we touched an abutting line in `E`, `F`, or `G`, we will have gotten a merge conflict at the time we ran `git cherry-pick`; we had to resolve it then.  We have to resolve it *again* now, in general.

> Side note: Git has a *re*-use *re*corded *re*solutions feature, `git rerere`, where once we've resolved some conflict, Git remembers both the original conflict and our resolution.  Git can then re-use the earlier re-corded re-solution (`rerere`), so that a later merge or cherry-pick doesn't require hand-resolving *again*.  Be careful with this: Git just records the *text* of the conflict and resolution, stripping off line numbers on purpopse, and can therefore mis-apply the recorded resolution later if it occurs in a different location where it needs some adjustment.  But it works pretty well in practice, and *all* merges require careful scrutiny and/or testing, because *all* automated procedures here can go wrong.  Git only works line-by-line, without any understanding of what it's merging.

#### Conclusion

To understand merge conflicts, look at diffs.  Find the *merge base*, by eyeballing the graph (`git log --graph`) or using `git merge-base --all` (see [the `git merge-base` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base)).  Run the two `git diff`s that Git will run; consider saving the output into a file since it tends to be large.  View the two diffs and observe where they overlap or abut: these are the conflicts.

Consider setting `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3`.  This will show merge conflicts in more detail, in the working tree copies of files.  Note that it has a drawback: the default `merge` conflict style lets Git do a partial resolution of the conflicts, which is often desirable; the `diff3` style does not.  (Git is acquiring a new third style that sits between these two, but I don't think it's released yet, as of Git 2.34.)

When Git *does* have a merge conflict, it leaves behind a mess.  You, as the programmer, are responsible for cleaning up this mess.  Git provides an additional set of tools—well, more of a tool *framework*, really—accessible via `git mergetool` that can assist in the mess-cleanup.  I rarely use them myself, but they do exist and it's worth learning about them, especially if you have and like third-party merge conflict resolution tools such as Beyond Compare or vimdiff.